# Unexpected result with python PLUP

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I followed a  [tutorial](http://isaacslavitt.com/2014/06/20/linear-optimization-in-python/) of python PLUP, but got a different result.
Instead of

```
Optimal weekly number of soldiers to produce: 20
Optimal weekly number of trains to produce: 60
```

I got:

```
Optimal weekly number of soldiers to produce: 0
Optimal weekly number of trains to produce: 0
```

but the rests are the same... If you want to know, that;s the code(almost copy and paste):

```
prob = pulp.LpProblem('Giapetto', pulp.LpMinimize)
soldiers = pulp.LpVariable('soldiers', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')
trains = pulp.LpVariable('trains', lowBound=0, cat='Integer')

raw_material_costs = 10 * soldiers + 9 * trains
variable_costs = 14 * soldiers + 10 * trains
revenues = 27 * soldiers + 21 * trains
profit = revenues - (raw_material_costs + variable_costs)
prob += profit

carpentry_hours = soldiers + trains
prob += (carpentry_hours <= 80)

finishing_hours = 2*soldiers + trains
prob += (finishing_hours <= 100)

prob += (soldiers <= 40)
print(prob)
optimization_result = prob.solve()
assert optimization_result == pulp.LpStatusOptimal

for var in (soldiers, trains):
    print('Optimal weekly number of {} to produce: {:1.0f}'.format(var.name, var.value()))
```

Any thing wrong?

Comment: Looks to me like you told it to minimize profit, and it has successfully minimized profit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's exactly doing what it should do.

You modified the most important thing, the objective:

```
prob = pulp.LpProblem('Giapetto', pulp.LpMinimize)
```

So you want to minimize the objective, which is:

```
profit = revenues - (raw_material_costs + variable_costs)
```

As both are only dependent on two variables, which are both nonnegative, the minimum value is 0.

You can reform your objective to see it can't be lower than 0 when both vars are nonnegative:

```
obj = 27 * soldiers + 21 trains - 24 soldiers - 19 trains
    = 3 * soldiers + 2 trains
```

Comment: Gosh... I enabled the auto-completion, didn't notice that... Thank you!